# Radeon X300-X500 series graphics card driver update?

Tags: windows-vista, graphics-card

I have a AMD Radeon X300-X500 series card and I am having some problems and would like to update the drivers to see if that fixes anything.

I went to the driver download center on the AMD site and searched for drivers for that series of card but the only drivers they had were DX9 and `dxdiag` says it currently supports DX11.

Is there any place that I can get a new driver for this card that supports DX11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a DirectX 9.0 card, have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ATI_Graphics_Processing_Units#PCIe_.28X3xx.2C_X5xx.2C_X6xx.2C_X10xx.29). Your card has been launched 2004, neither DirectX 10 nor 11 were specified back then.

Also from [Wikipedia is this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon#Processor_generations) info from a table:

```
Retail/card series name: R9500-R9800, X300-X600, X1050

Chip series: R300

Graphics APIs support: DirectX 9.0, OpenGL 2.0

Notes: ATI's DirectX 9.0 technology, released in 2002, incorporated pixel shader.
       Included in this generation are Radeon 9500–9800, X300–X600, and X1050.
```

The version of DirectX a card supports can not be upgraded by a driver.

Comment: To clarify, dxdiag says the *current version of the software installed will run up to DX11*, not that your GPU actually can support it.